# How to save the keyboard entered value in a notepad file using cmd or powershell

Tags: c, cmd

I want to save the full output of the below C program in a .txt file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a, b, c;

printf("Enter two numbers to add\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

c = a + b;

printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);
getch();

}
```

I used the following commands in cmd prompt. But it just shows the printf value alone and not save the scanf value(the keyboard inserted value).

```
C:\Programs\Ramkumar>sample.exe /all > file.txt
```

Can anyone provide me the command for the full output to save in txt file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are only redirecting the standard output to the `file.txt` and when you press the keyboard button, that's the input from standard input device. to save the inputs, you will have to read the input first and write it to a file/standard output so that it could be redirected.

so after you read the input, what you can do is print it out so that it goes to `file.txt`